# No kernel output after booting LFS

Tags: linux, boot, grub, kernel, console

Whenever I tried to build LFS (Linux from scratch), I don't get any unexpected errors but however, after rebooting all I can see is just grub message from `grub-mkconfig` which says: `Loading Linux 5.19.2 ...`, and no kernel output, I cannot see anything, disk activity also lights up for about 6/7 seconds, but what's strange is I can type root then password then reboot command and system reboots, I also checked `/var/log/boot.log` and `/var/log/kern.log` and I can confirm that system boots up perfectly, but stuck at grub's booting screen.

I tried blacklisting `nouveau`, setting grub `terminal_output` to `console`, adding no `nomodeset` and `loglevel=7` to the kernel parameters, but still no luck.

Any help appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: "*I don't get any unexpected errors*" -- Your negative statement is ambiguous.  Does it mean that you do get "*expected*" errors?  How do you "*cannot see anything*" but somehow mange to check log files?

Comment: @sawdust yes there are expected test errors at chroot building, which could happen and have their reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I forgot to build kernel with framebuffer drivers (especially EFI one):

.config:

```
CONFIG_FB_VESA=y
CONFIG_FB_EFI=y
CONFIG_FB_SIMPLE=y
```